# Autofit scrolll bar in gridview with max display limit as 10

Tags: asp.net, gridview

framework:.net 4.0
I have a grid. I want scroll bar to be implemented in it. The gridview should display a max of 10 records in it. If the records are less than 10, the size of the gridview should adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use div or panel as below if you need only vertical scroll bar

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: scroll">your GridView</div>
```

or you can use

[Scrollable GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/573044/Extending-ASP-Net-Controls-a-Scrollable-GridView)

Comment: In this case we get the scroll bar even if there are no records in it..I dont want the scorll bar when there are no records..

Comment: mate you can set div height with java script or code behind according to your need.